# Transitioning from one anim to another based on which frame the anim is in

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, animator

I am using 2D sprites in a 3D environment (with Blend Trees to imply three dimenionality upon camera rotation), and my Animator for the player gameObject needs to be able to switch between several different animation clips based on which frame the clip is at.

For instance, I have an idle anim wherein the player gameObject shifts her weight from one foot to the other. I also have two "transition" anims, one for each foot. And I also have a walk anim. So if the gameObject is, say, between frames 0-20, then needs to transition to the "leftFoot" transition anim before then transitioning into the walk anim. Similarly, if the idle anim is between frames 21-40, the gameObject needs to transition to "rightFoot" transition anim followed by the walk anim.

I think I'm on the right track by looking up Unity scripting documentation about the Animation and AnimationClip methods, but I'm not sure which functions are helpful in this case. And are certain Animator parameters better to use over others (bools, triggers)?

Comment: Jason, what are you trying to achieve? Seems like you are complicating a simple problem. Why do you need to control left and right foot separately? Usually you shouldn't care what frame is animation at. Blend trees or transition parameters should handle all well. You can also make use of calling events at certain frames. https://answers.unity.com/questions/477956/call-function-dependent-on-frame-of-animation.html

Comment: It does seem more complicated than it should be, admittedly. It's a 2D sprite, not a 3D model, which is why I have separate transition anims leading to the same walk anim. I want a smoother transition which is why I made two separate transition anims. Does that make it clearer?

Comment: Hi Jason, you just need idle and walk animations and Unity will take care of the transitions as I said. It doesn't matter whether you have 2d or 3d animations. If you can try to put some video and screenshots so we can talk on the specifics of it more easily.